# Anaconda getting error message when trying to run setup.py

Tags: python, error-handling, anaconda, setup.py

It stops at the setup. All other lines of code seem to work fine. I'm using anaconda. I tried to uninstall it and reinstall it again, but it hasn't fixed the issue. I'm on macOS and using Jupyter notebook.

The error I get:

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Izzyy/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/fancy_getopt.py", line 233, in getopt
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(args, short_opts, self.long_opts)
  File "/Users/Izzyy/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/getopt.py", line 95, in getopt
    opts, args = do_shorts(opts, args[0][1:], shortopts, args[1:])
  File "/Users/Izzyy/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/getopt.py", line 195, in do_shorts
    if short_has_arg(opt, shortopts):
  File "/Users/Izzyy/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/getopt.py", line 211, in short_has_arg
    raise GetoptError(_('option -%s not recognized') % opt, opt)
getopt.GetoptError: option -f not recognized

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in find_recursion(etype, value, records)
    380     # first frame (from in to out) that looks different.
    381     if not is_recursion_error(etype, value, records):
--> 382         return len(records), 0
    383 
    384     # Select filename, lineno, func_name to track frames with

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: its a lot longer but it won't allow me to post the full error code

Comment: Could you add what you are trying to install and what your exact command was?